# cast/spread 2 columns based on one shared factor

Tags: r

I am struggling with this - sorry. This is my haves:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

haves <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    , factor1 = c("f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1")
    , factor2 = c("f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2")
    , number_1 = c(1,2,3,10,11)
    , number_2 = c(43,44,45,52,53)
    , age = c(2, 2, 2, 9, 9)
    , date1 = c(as.Date("2014-07-01"), as.Date("2014-07-01"), as.Date("2014-07-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01"))
    , y = c(554.5, 554.5, 554.5, 616, 616)
    , x = c(2,1,0,3,0)
)

haves

  id factor1 factor2 number_1 number_2 age      date1     y x
1  1      f1      f2        1       43   2 2014-07-01 554.5 2
2  1      f1      f2        2       44   2 2014-07-01 554.5 1
3  1      f1      f2        3       45   2 2014-07-01 616.0 0
4  1      f1      f2       10       52   9 2015-02-01 616.0 3
5  1      f1      f2       11       53   9 2015-02-01 616.0 0
```

I want to cast/spread the values in number_1 and number_2 according to x to get this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need `tidyr::pivot_wider(haves, names_from = x, values_from = starts_with('number'))`

Comment: thanks. my actual naming are not actually like this nut I will have a look at pivot_wider, which looks interesting. never heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a `pivot_wider` solution:

```r
library(tidyr)

haves %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = starts_with("number_"), values_fill = 0)
```

gives you

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 14
     id factor1 factor2   age date1          y number_1_2 number_1_1 number_1_0 number_1_3 number_2_2 number_2_1 number_2_0
  <dbl> <fct>   <fct>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 f1      f2          2 2014-07-01  554.          1          2          3          0         43         44         45
2     1 f1      f2          9 2015-02-01  616           0          0         11         10          0          0         53
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried something along those lines but I get 3 rows (as you) but the wants is 2 rows ... why is that?

Comment: @cs0815 `date1` and `y` have 3 combinations, so there are at least 3 rows after `pivot_wider()`.

Comment: What is your condition to drop a row from your data?

Comment: well the rest are really id vars ... i will try this. need to get it in the wants format. this id_cols = C("id", "factor1", "factor2", "age", "date1", "y") does not work, can make them factors maybe

Comment: sorry am I missing something c(554.5, 554.5, 554.5, 616, 616) == c(554.5, 554.5, 554.5, 616, 616). i appreciate that 2 levels 2015-02-01 + 2014-07-01 and 554.5 + 616 give 4 combinations but the rest are id columns if you like: id_cols = C("id", "factor1", "factor2", "age", "date1", "y"). Maybe I have to combine all the columns to one to make it unique. Hope this makes sense? Is the wants not showing this? Thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake myself: if your y is given by `c(554.5, 554.5, 554.5, 616, 616)` instead of `c(554.5, 554.5, 616, 616, 616)` you'll get two rows. But that's not the data you provided. Perhaps there is a mistake?

Comment: @cs0815 It's possible to merge the rows by date. But what is the condition to drop one of the two possibilities of `y`? Why, in your case, the data are `date = 2014-07-01` and `y = 554.5` instead of `date = 2014-07-01` and `y = 616`. Your question doesn't give a condtion for that.

Comment: oops - appologies - I see the error now. I will change the haves.

Comment: Please replace NAs with zero as well - I will then accept. Thanks!!!!

Comment: `replace(is.na(.), 0)` replaces NAs in all columns, which also influences values in `id_cols`. That works on this question but will make trouble in other cases. The standard solution should be replacing NAs only in those columns selected by `values_from`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks for your feedback. You are right. I changed my answer and included `values_fill`. Had some issues using that since I ran on `tidyr 1.0.2`... Updated and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution using `dcast()`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(haves), ... ~ x, value.var = paste0("number_", 1:2), fill = 0)
```

> ```
>    id factor1 factor2 age      date1     y number_1_0 number_1_1 number_1_2 number_1_3 number_2_0 number_2_1
> 1:  1      f1      f2   2 2014-07-01 554.5          3          2          1          0         45         44
> 2:  1      f1      f2   9 2015-02-01 616.0         11          0          0         10         53          0
>    number_2_2 number_2_3
> 1:         43          0
> 2:          0         52
> ```

`pivot_wider()` also has a parameter to fill in missing values. So, there is no need for a separate call to `replace(is.na(.), 0)`:

```
library(tidyr)
haves %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = starts_with("number_"), values_fill = 0)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 14
>      id factor1 factor2   age date1          y number_1_2 number_1_1 number_1_0 number_1_3 number_2_2 number_2_1
>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1     1 f1      f2          2 2014-07-01  554.          1          2          3          0         43         44
> 2     1 f1      f2          9 2015-02-01  616           0          0         11         10          0          0
> # ... with 2 more variables: number_2_0 <dbl>, number_2_3 <dbl>
> ```

Note that the column order after reshaping is different. While `dcast()` orders columns by value of `x`, i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3`, `pivot_wider()` orders columns by appearance, i.e., `2, 1, 0, 3`.

Comment: thanks. I was going to use dcast - is ... a valid expression or what goes there please? Thanks!

Comment: According to `?data.table::dcast`, `...` is a special variable in the formula which represents all variables not otherwise mentioned in the formula.

Comment: thanks. no offence - accepted the other earlier answer but yours is great too!

Comment: No worries. That's fine for me.

Comment: @Uwe Included `values_fill = 0` after updating. I should keep track of my package versions.

Comment: @MartinGal, I'm glad you picked up my suggestion concerning `values_fill` because I didn't want to edit your answer. Now, I would remove the `pivot_wider()` part from my answer but I find the difference in column order worth to be documented.